# What does the (?) mean in this line? - ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, .net

What does the question mark (?) in the following method declaration mean?

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
```

Comment: I've linked to a pre-existing question with great answers; for info, I simply searched for "c# question mark after type"

Answer (score 3):

It means that int variable is nullable.

So, you can place a null value in the variable.

You can see more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=netcore-3.1)